# What is the equivalent of the integers symbol Z for n bit only integers?

Tags: terminology, notation, integers, number-formats

We refer to the set of all integers as $\mathbb{Z}$.  Now suppose we have a set of integers that can be held within a computer variable of $n$ bits width. Clearly they can only be of  $2^{n}$ range, signed or not. How would we symbolise that? Is there something that is done to the zed, or does it remain simply $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You could always represent it as integers in the appropriate range, $\{i \mid i \in [0, 2^n] \land i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Or even more concisely: $[0, 2^n] \cap \mathbb{Z}$. Apparently [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Integer_intervals) also mentions a notation for integer ranges: $[0 .. 2^n]$.

Comment: I guess technically it would only go from 0 to $2^n-1$ but you get the idea. Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2056522/445911).

Answer (score 2):

For bounded sets, the usual convention is to use interval notation.

Specifically, $[a,b]$ means "real numbers between $a$ and $b$, inclusive", while $[a\mathinner{\ldotp \ldotp}b]$ means "integers between $a$ and $b$, inclusive". Changing any of the square brackets to curved means that endpoint is not included: $a \not\in (a,b]$, for example.

In this case, you'd want the interval $[0\mathinner{\ldotp \ldotp}2^n)$. Or, if you think the delimiters look mismatched and weird, you can use $[0\mathinner{\ldotp \ldotp}2^n-1]$.

P.S. LaTeX doesn't have a builtin for "two dots", so I used `\mathinner{\ldotp \ldotp}` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304667/169121).

Comment: In [here](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) it looks like `\enleadertwodots` could work, but not quite. There's also `\hdotdot` which is weird why they don't have `\ldotdot`.

Comment: @ryan Ah, good find! And yeah, I'm surprised `\ldotdot` isn't a standard symbol, since I've seen this in more papers than many of the other mathfont symbols. But, it's not too hard to fake, thankfully.

Comment: Actually yes, `\enleadertwodots` works perfect (well, maybe not perfect, but close) if you use the `stix` package. However, the name is not very appealing.

Comment: Here, you can see for yourself: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485694/138833.